# Summarizing data by current and previous month from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to summarize data by this and previous month. My table looks like this:

```
Date        Client  Amount
2019-06-02  111     100
2019-06-03  111      90
2019-06-22  222      80
2019-07-02  111     110
2019-07-03  111     120
```

Expected result:

```
Client   This_month    Previous_month
111      230           190           
222                    80
```

Thank you for any hints how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by client` and use conditional aggregation:

```
select
  client,
  sum(case when last_day(date) = last_day(current_date) then amount end) This_month,
  sum(case when last_day(date) = last_day(current_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) then amount end) Previous_month    
from tablename
group by client
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/whhbCEcYNDXyY4iNQ4wMTL/0).
Results:

```
| client | This_month | Previous_month |
| ------ | ---------- | -------------- |
| 111    | 230        | 190            |
| 222    |            | 80             |
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a pair of left join

```
select  a.Client, b.act_amount, c.prev_amount
from (
    select distinct client 
    from my_table
) a
left join (
    select month(date) act_mont, client, sum(amount) act_amount
    from my_table 
    where month(date) = month(curdate)
    group by month(date), client
) b on a.client = b.client 
left join (
    select month(date) prev_mont, client, sum(amount) prev_amount
    from my_table 
    where month(date) = month(curdate) -1
    group by month(date), client
) c on a.client = c.client
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. How about using stored procedure?

Comment: why ... store procedure??' .. this is just a select ..  you have not update or insert  ..